# Pillow returns the error : "IOError: image file is truncated (6 bytes not processed)"

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, python-imaging-library

I use Pillow 4.1.1 with Python 2.7 / Django 1.9

I have dozens of thousands of user-uploaded pictures on my website and I use pillow to generate thumbnails from the templates.

E.g.:

```
{% thumbnail apicture.file "1200x350" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width=100%>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

It was working very well until this week. Django now shows this error:

```
IOError: image file is truncated (6 bytes not processed)
```

Solutions found on stackoverflow do not work, as they all apply to views and not templates (e.g. ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True).

Is there a simple way to identify which pictures generate this error ? How to solve this bug ?

Here is the full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /trip/province-dublin-2034
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)    
  File "C:\Terradiem\terradiem\trip\views.py", line 300, in trip
    return render(request, 'trip/results.html', qsall)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 97, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 95, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 206, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 92, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 220, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 220, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 326, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\templatetags\thumbnail.py", line 59, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\templatetags\thumbnail.py", line 137, in _render
    thumbnail = get_thumbnail(file_, geometry, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\shortcuts.py", line 8, in get_thumbnail
    return default.backend.get_thumbnail(file_, geometry_string, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\base.py", line 125, in get_thumbnail
    thumbnail)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\base.py", line 157, in _create_thumbnail
    image = default.engine.create(source_image, geometry, options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\engines\base.py", line 21, in create
    image = self.colorspace(image, geometry, options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\engines\base.py", line 53, in colorspace
    return self._colorspace(image, colorspace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sorl\thumbnail\engines\pil_engine.py", line 101, in _colorspace
    return image.convert('RGB')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 844, in convert
self.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 226, in load
"(%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
IOError: image file is truncated (6 bytes not processed)
```

Thank you

Comment: Most likely, the header of the image in question contains wrong information on content length (may be corrupt). You can solve this by explicitly catching and processing that error, possibly testing for content length info from header at the same time.

Comment: Just do `ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True` as you've already found as early as possible in your django app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok, I got the answer to my own question!

As commented by lepsch, just add

`from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True`

as early possible in the django app. I added it to the view generating the page, and it works fine.